# C# textBox issue in LINUX with windows compiled exe (MONO)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mono, ubuntu-12.04

I have a little issue with my simple serial GUI application.

I use Visual studio 2012 and C# to build a serial GUI that received basically just text.
Then I display it in a textBox:

Everything is working fine in the Window application. 
Then I wanted to try to run it on my Ubuntu 12.04.

So I checked with  [Moma](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) if there were no problem to run it afterwards. 
Once again everything is good.

Then I run my exe on Linux with mono (Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2) )

Everything works fine (serial connection (with a sudo otherwise can't have access), buttons etc. ) but I have no display of the text in the textBox even though I see on my RX LED of my Xbee that I definitely receive something.

That's where I am stuck, I can't find why this is the only part of the program that is not fully working at the time !

Thanks for your help

Comment: same for me, still haven't found any solution or explanation